# NTLM Authentication with request-ntlm

Tags: node.js, express, ntlm

I'm using **request-ntlm** package on my Node middleware to make connection to a distant Azure server. My credentials are valid since the connection is working in Insomnia (a REST client), but I keep having the same error while connecting from Node:

```
events.js:176
domain.enter();
       ^

TypeError: domain.enter is not a function
    at Request.emit (events.js:176:12)
    at Request.start (C:\Users\DJ5629\Documents\powerbi\node_modules\request\req
uest.js:750:10)
    at Request.end (C:\Users\DJ5629\Documents\powerbi\node_modules\request\reque
st.js:1512:10)
    at end (C:\Users\DJ5629\Documents\powerbi\node_modules\request\request.js:56
1:14)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DJ5629\Documents\powerbi\node_modules\req
uest\request.js:575:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

Here is the code I'm using to make the NTLM request:

```
let opts = {
    url: api+'Contracts/getAll',
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json'
    },
    workstation: 'WRKSTN',
    domain: 'arandom.domain.com'

  }

  ntlm.get(opts, function(err,response){
    if(!error){
      res.status(response.statusCode).send(response);
    } else {
      res.status(response.statusCode);
    }
  })
```

This error is only thrown when I give a domain name in the options, however I don't get any answer when I remove the **domain** property.

System information:
 - Windows 7 Enterprise Edition
 - Node v6.11.4

Thanks for your help

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Nope, thankfully we switched to AWS, so no more ntlm :)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug in the original code library where they were re-using the `domain` member from the `request` library causing a naming conflict. As the original author appears to be no longer maintaining the library, a fixed package has been created under [request-nplm-continued](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ntlm-continued).